# Writing a function that executes lambda/invocable only in debug builds

Tags: c++

I want to write a function `do_in_debug()` which shall take a lambda/invocable that accesses members/objects which only exist in a debug configuration:

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct debug_line {};
#ifdef NDEBUG
inline constexpr bool debug_mode = false;
#else
inline constexpr bool debug_mode = true;
#endif

template<bool Debug = debug_mode>
struct debug_info{
};

//debug_info has data in debug builds only
template<>
struct debug_info<true>{
    std::vector<debug_line> debug_lines;
};

struct Foo {
    debug_info<> info;
};

template<bool Debug = debug_mode,typename Func>
void doInDebug(Func f) {
    if constexpr(debug_mode) {
        f();
    }
}

void foo(Foo& foo) {
    doInDebug([&foo]() {
        auto& l = foo.info.debug_lines[0]; // compile error even though when this lambda is invoked debug_mode is true and debug_info is not empty
    });
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    foo(f);
    return 0;
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/bPTYTxnvh)

is that even possible?

```
<source>:33:28: error: 'struct debug_info<>' has no member named 'debug_lines'; did you mean 'debug_info'?
   33 |         auto& l = foo.info.debug_lines[0]; // compile error even though when this lambda is invoked debug_mode is true and debug_info is not empty
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            debug_info
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us your errors. Preferably a copy-paste of the full build-log.

Comment: `foo.debugLines[0]` -> `foo.info.debugLines[0]`

Comment: If the debug/not debug is indicated by NDEBUG, why not `#ifndef NDEBUG`?

Comment: While macros and conditional compilation in many cases can (and should) be avoided in C++, this is actually a perfect example of when they make sense. No need to bother with the templates, just a single `#ifdef NDEBUG ... #else ... #endif` for the functions and types themselves. Even better, if possibly work with the requirements and design to see if you can avoid the debug-specific code at all.

Comment: I get this is just example code, but: a function `foo()` that takes a `struct Foo`. Really? What about good ol' `bar` and `baz`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess I was overcomplicating things. A simple macro `#define do_in_debug(x) { \
x \
}` works, too i guess.